# how to add comma between 2 charachters in shell

Tags: regex, awk

I have as input a string with 1 uppercase letter or a string with 2 uppercase letters
Here after Example of input string:

```
AB
AN
FG
K
M
```

I want to execute a shell command/function that translate the input string to 2 lower case letters separated by comma "," (in case the input is 2 uppercase letters) or 1  lower case letter (in case the input is 1 uppercase letter) the

outputs of the above examples

```
a,b
a,n
f,g
k
m
```

I tried this one

```
(echo -n "${s:0:1}" && [ "${s,1:1}" != "" ] && echo -n ",${s:1:1}") | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

But I think there is simplest solution with sed / awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""; OFS=","} {$0 = tolower($0); $1=$1} 1' file
```

```
a,b
a,n
f,g
k
m
```

**Details:**

- `FS=""`: Use an empty field separator splitting each character as separate field
- `OFS=","`: Using output field separator as `,`
- `$0 = tolower($0)`: Lowercase all uppercase characters
- `$1=$1`: Force `awk` to rewrite each record using `OFS` value
- `1`: Print each record

---

**Alternative Solution:**

In case your `awk` doesn't support `FS=""` (empty field separator), use this solution:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{$0 = tolower($0); gsub(/[a-z]/, "&,"); sub(/,$/, "")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0);gsub(/[a-z]/,"&,");sub(/,$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** First converting whole line to small letters by `tolower` then globally substitute every letter with letter and `,`. Finally substituting last occurring `,` with NULL then by mentioning `1` printing the edited line.

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\L&,/g;s/,$//' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `awk` is `gawk`...
`awk -v FS='' '$0=tolower($0) {$1=$1}1' OFS=',' myFile`

Comment: You should mention which awks that will work in since having a null FS is undefined behavior per POSIX.